# Why does Angular 5 Transition throw AppComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, animation

Why does Angular 5 throw this error?

```
AppComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

I am working on a proof-of-concept for Angular animations and I'm using the code directly from the site. My component looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate, keyframes } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-obj-list',
  templateUrl: './obj-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./obj-list.component.css'],
    animations: [

    trigger('myAwesomeAnimation', [
        state('small', style({
            transform: 'scale(1)',
        })),
        state('large', style({
            transform: 'scale(1.2)',
        })),
    ]),
    transition('small => large', animate('100ms ease-in'))

    ]
})
export class ObjListComponent implements OnInit {
  state = 'small';
  constructor() { }
  animateMe() {
     this.state = (this.state === 'small' ? 'large' : 'small');
       }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The line of code that the error references is just the tag to include my component: `<app-obj-list></app-obj-list>`

I've narrowed it down to the line in the above file: `transition('small => large', animate('100ms ease-in'))`

When I remove that line, the error goes away. When I leave it in, I get the error:

```
AppComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at new AnimationTrigger (browser.js:3017)
    at buildTrigger (browser.js:3005)
    at InjectableAnimationEngine.AnimationEngine.registerTrigger (browser.js:5504)
    at eval (animations.js:291)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at AnimationRendererFactory.createRenderer (animations.js:290)
    at DebugRendererFactory2.createRenderer (core.js:15075)
    at createComponentView (core.js:13633)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15041)
    at Object.debugCreateComponentView [as createComponentView] (core.js:14370)
```

My app.module has the BrowserAnimationsModule so that shouldn't be the issue:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ObjListComponent } from './obj-list/obj-list.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ObjListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I'm trying to follow the code on the [angular site](https://angular.io/guide/animations) as closely as I can. Can someone tell me what I'm forgetting? Is there an import I'm forgetting?
 Is there a package I need to download? I'm new to Angular and Angular animations and I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: I'm not using a forEach. That's what confuses me. This is just as bare-bones as I can make it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you look closely at the tutorial, the "transition" property of the animation needs to be inside of the array of "trigger":

```
animations: [
    trigger('myAwesomeAnimation', [
        state('small', style({
            transform: 'scale(1)',
        })),
        state('large', style({
            transform: 'scale(1.2)',
        })), 
        transition('small => large', animate('100ms ease-in'))
    ]) // close the array after the transition
]
```

Comment: Oh dang! It's the smallest things that trip us up sometimes! Thanks so much! I can't accept your answer for 8 minutes but I will as soon as I can. You rock!

Comment: @Knight thanks! Glad that I can help. I could not test it, but if it does not work, just comment here.

Comment: Worked For Me Thank You